# Flash Pro Hyperlink button error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cc

I have created a  button  using  flash Pro cc I've been doing research but was unable to find why a TypeError stating

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.at PD3Subscribenow_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

I have placed my code on a action layer on frame 1:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
sub_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myButtonFunction);
function myButtonFunction(event: MouseEvent) {
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http//:www.google.com");
navigateToURL(request, "_blank");
}
```

and gave the instance name of my button "sub_btn".

Can you tell me where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Most likely `sub_btn` is null.   are you sure it's available on frame 1 with that instance name?

Comment: Only the actionscript on the first frame but the sub_btn is on another frame but would that class it as null

Answer (score 0):

You issue is that on the frame where the code executes,  `sub_btn` does not yet exist (as you state in your comments that it is on a later frame).

You either need to:

1. **Move the button to the first frame,**

or

2. **Move the code that references it to the frame with the button.**

Answer (score -1):

The problem maybe that Flash does not recognize that your button exists yet. In Flash Builder I would use

```
 creationComplete="init()"
```

and then

```
 private function init():void{
    sub_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myButtonFunction)
 }
```

Comment: This is not a flash builder question