# Flash AS3 Pass my var data to another frame

Tags: java, android, actionscript-3, flash

I'm using AS3 / AIR 3.2 for Android.
I'm having a trouble about passing my variable data to another frame. I read some forums about this but I'm only new this so I don't have yet any idea.
I have an input text and button in my frame 1 where the user will input a name then the data entered will be save. (I used SharedObject) but all the data inputted will appear on frame 2. 
While my frame 2 is a dynamic text where all the data will appear. 
This is the code for my frame 1

```
import flash.net.SharedObject;
var myName:String;
myResult.text = "";
var mySO:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("test");
if (mySO1.data.myName != null){
    myResult.text = mySO1.data.myName;
}
else {
    myResult.text = "No Name";
}

submit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotomyNextFrame);
function gotomyNextFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    nextFrame();
    myName = myInputName.text;
    trace(myName);
    myResult.text = myName;
    mySO.data.myResult = myInputName.text;
    mySO.flush();
    trace(mySO.data.myResult);
}
```

Error: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. I think this is because I'm wrong in passing of data into frame.
Attempt: I tried show the output on the same frame and I didn't encounter any error.

Comment: Most likely your problem is that your trying to access an object (text field) that only exists on frame 2,  from frame 1.  Am I right?  If your text field isn't on frame 1 with the instance name of `myResult` then the code will throw the 1009 error.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27024406/1457439

Comment: @LDMS yes LDMS, I did that on purpose because I want my frame 2 to access the data from frame 1. I want to show the data entered from frame 1 to frame 2.

Comment: Then you have to wait to reference the frame 2 text field until you are ON frame 2.  Just move `myResult.text = myName;` from the `gotomyNextFrame` function on frame 1, to frame 2.   You'll also need to take all other frame 1 references to `myResult` out as well

Answer (score 1):

Your `SharedObject` var is `mySO` and not `mySO1`, and to share data between frames, you can use a variable like this :

**frame 1 :**

```
...

var shared_data:String = txt_input.text

nextFrame()

...
```

**frame 2 :**

```
// get shared_data and use it as you like

another_input.text = shared_data

shared_object.data.current_name = shared_data

...
```

**Edit :**

```
/* frame 01 */

// shared_data should be declared here to be a global var not inside a function
var shared_data:String      

submit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotomyNextFrame)
function gotomyNextFrame(event:MouseEvent):void { 

    // here you should just assign a value to shared_data var
    shared_data = yourName.text     

    nextFrame() 

} 

/* frame 2 */

stop()

import flash.net.SharedObject

// if you redefine shared_data var here you will lost it's value and you will get a null value
// var shared_data:String       

var mySO:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("test1")

myResult.text = shared_data

// here your SharedObject object is named mySO and not SharedObject
//SharedObject.data.mySO = shared_data  

mySO.data.yourName = shared_data
```

Comment: Ok thanks somehow I get it, but how about this one? " Error 1119: Access of possibly undefined property"? I read some from other forum but I didn't create any class, does it mean I need to create one?

Comment: @EyrhonGonzales In which line you have got that error ? Could you put your code ?

Comment: //frame 1 submit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotomyNextFrame);

function gotomyNextFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 var shared_data:String = yourName.text
 nextFrame();
}
//frrame 2 stop();
import flash.net.SharedObject;
var shared_data:String;
var mySO:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("test1");
myResult.text = shared_data;
SharedObject.data.mySO = shared_data; @akmozo

Comment: I have an error: "Error #2007: Parameter text must be non-null."

Comment: You should type something in the text input of the 1st frame or add an `if` like this : `if(shared_data != null){ myResult.text = shared_data; mySO.data.yourName = shared_data; } `.